# Render list of byte array images

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have list of byte array image list,those I have retrived in one
request in a servlet,now my problem is I want to render it one by one in my
jsp page ,I want to know how to do it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are small, you could use base64 encoding on each image using a library. [Apache Commons Base64](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec//apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html). Once you have encoded each image, you can just return the list of all the encoded strings, and display in the JSP.